# Android apk size large due to libnativebridge.so in apk

Tags: android, google-play, proguard, minify

We found our app of 113mbs has a binary called libNativeBridge.so in 5 architectures [x86x64, x86, arm64-v8a, armabi-v7a, armabi] which takes up 83mb by itself.

- What is this library used for?
- Will the app be optimized and thinned when downloading from google play on phones which don't use the other architectures?
- How do I reduce the app size apart from minifying, useProguard and shrinkResources options I used for the app?

[image]

Comment: Also have similar issue, this libNativeBridge.so takes up more than 40% of apk size. Any hints on this ?